# Kotlin: Null check in if block

Tags: kotlin

I started to learn Kotlin recently. One thing I can't get my head around is the null check blocks. The following statement is considered unsafe, and the compiler won't allow you to compile this.

```
    var testVar: String? = null;

    // if (testVar != null )
    {
        // Doing some work....
        println(testVar.length)
    }
```

But when you uncomment the `if` line, everything works. This seems great.

**But what if** `// Doing some work....` is computationally expensive and another thread changes the value of `testVar` to `null` while this thread is in `// Doing some work` line? In this scenario:

- Does the program throw a NullPointerException?
- OR:
- Does the bytecode cache the value of testVar and use the cached value inside the if block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your initial example, is your `var` local to a function? For example:

```
fun doStuff() {
    var testVar: String? = null

    if (testVar != null) {
        println(testVar.length)
    }
}
```

In this case, no other scope has reference to `testVar` so nothing else can change it. However, if the `var` is a class property, i.e.

```
class MyClass {
    var testVar: String? = null

    fun doStuff() {
        if (testVar != null) {
            println(testVar.length)
        }
    }
}
```

This will fail to compile as `testVar` could have been set to null by another thread in between the check and the usage.

Going further, if you try to be tricky:

```
fun doStuff() {
    var testVar: String? = null

    fun trickyFunction() {
        testVar = null
    }

    if (testVar != null) {
        trickyFunction()
        println(testVar.length)
    }
}
```

The compiler will fail as your variable is captured by a changing closure. So in general, if you are able to use the variable via a smart-cast to non-null, you should not have to worry about any potential for NPEs.

For the second scenario (var properties) it is preferable to rely on `.let` to capture an immutable reference to the current value, i.e.

```
testVar?.let { capturedTestVar ->
    println(capturedTestVar.length)
}
```

Comment: There's actually a bunch of built-in scoping functions that come in handy depending on context: [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/let.html) [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html) [`also`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html) [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html).